# React router dom - Link. How can I put an ID into the path of Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So I am mapping over an array of users, and each user has a unique ID. I am wanting to create a path for the link which will include the unique ID of the user, depending on which link is clicked. Here is what I have tried so far (Link does not allow me to use template literals for some reason)

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
//import {axiosWithAuth} from '../api/axiosWithAuth';
//import axios from 'axios';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {useParams, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {fetchUsers} from '../actions/index';

//get request to /api/users -- will return array of users

const ListUsers = props =>{
    const [data, setData] = useState([{username:'hello world!'}]);
    const params = useParams();
    const path = `/Profile/${params.id}`

    // function myFunction(id) {
    //    alert(item.id);
    // }

    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchUsers();
    }, [])

    return(
        <div>
            {props.users.map(item=>{return(
            <Link path='/Profile' params={{id: item.id}}>
                <div className="UsersCard">Username: {item.username} <br /> Name: {item.firstName} <br /> ID: {item.id} <br /> Email: {item.email} </div>
            </Link>
                )})}
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        users: state.users, 
        user: {}, 
        registerSuccessMessage: '',
        user_stories: {}, 
        isLoading: false, 
        error: null 
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchUsers})(ListUsers);

//get request to /api/users/:id -- will return users specified by ID
```

Here is my routes

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import PrivateRoute from './api/PrivateRoute';
import SignIn from './Components/SignIn';
import SignUp from "./Components/SignUp";
import Profile from './Components/Profile';
import Stories from './Components/Stories';
import Nav from "./Components/Nav";
import ListUsers from './Components/ListUsers';
import EditUser from './Components/EditUser';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Nav/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/SignIn' component={SignIn} />
          <Route path='/SignUp' component={SignUp} />
          <Route exact path='/' />
          <PrivateRoute path='/UsersList' component={ListUsers} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path='/Profile/:id' component={Profile} />
          <PrivateRoute path='/Stories' component={Stories} />
          <PrivateRoute path='/Profile/:id/editProfile' component={EditUser} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want it to take me to the '/Profile/:id' route according to whichever user is clicked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<Link to={`/Profile/${item.id}`}>
  ... 
</Link>
```

For search params you can pass an object.

```
<Link to={{
    pathname: "/Profile",
    search: "?key=value",
  }}>
   ...
</Link>
```

[Version 5 Docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)
[Version 6 Docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link)

Comment: Oh my gosh, I forgot my curly braces. That's why it wasn't letting me use template literals. Silly mistake, thank you so much dw_!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to wrap the path with curly braces and then use any javascript you want & also template literals

```
<div>
            {props.users.map(item=>{return(
            <Link path={`/Profile/${item.id}`}>
                <div className="UsersCard">Username: {item.username} <br /> Name: {item.firstName} <br /> ID: {item.id} <br /> Email: {item.email} </div>
            </Link>
                )})}
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes I was missing my curly braces, that's why it wasn't letting me use template literals. Thank you very much KR!

Answer (score 0):

id value is better to be included into link path.

```
<Link path={`/Profile/${item.id}`} params={{id: item.id}}>
```

It makes things working wherever user gets link from.

Comment: Great to know! I was just missing my curly braces, thank you for your advice though Tarukami!