# In React-Router-Dom how do I go to another page while also going to an id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using React-Router-Dom in one of my projects and am trying to go to another page while also going to an id. I have a

```
let linkTo = /Countries#Germany
<Link to={linkTo}></Link>
```

And when I press the Link it only goes to the Countries page and not to the element in the other page with the id of Germany. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React router dom - Link. How can I put an ID into the path of Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63614183/react-router-dom-link-how-can-i-put-an-id-into-the-path-of-link)

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to go to the subsection in the Countries page where there's a Germany section?

If so, there's no way to do this out of the box with React Router, unfortunately, but there's a very easy library that does it.

[React Router hash link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link)

The docs explain it, but literally all you do it is:

1. Add the library and import the Hashlink into your React module.
2. Replace your  components with the  -- keep the `to` prop the same value.
3. Add the hashlink as the `id` on the component you're trying to nav to. For ex., add the `#Germany` id on the Germany component. These ids can be added dynamically if you're using dynamic components.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `:id` to the route definition, then pass the value of the id to the route inside the Link component:

```
<Route name="route name" path="/:id or param name" component={<component/>} />
```

Then

```
<Link to={'/route name/id value'} />
```

View more ways on the official [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)