# Anchor href=#id is not working in react-router-dom Link

Tags: reactjs, anchor, react-router-dom

Here is simple anchor tag `<a href='#about'/>About</a>`. It scrolls down to element with about id. But I can not do the same with `react-router Link`. I tried `<Link to='#about'/>` but it did not work. What can I do in this case?

Comment: I think this question can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63614183/react-router-dom-link-how-can-i-put-an-id-into-the-path-of-link

Comment: [karina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10405683/vyctoria-karina) but it is a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `react-router-hash-link`. See this issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/394).